# Arraylist and list issue in C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have a arraylist of employees from the gridview in my ASP.net Page as shown below:

```
ArrayList tempempList = new ArrayList();
        List<Employee> emps = new List<Employee>();
        for (int i = 0; i < gvemp.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)gvemp.Rows[i].FindControl("cbAssign")).Checked)
            {
                tempempList.Add(((Label)gvemp.Rows[i].FindControl("lblempSeqNo")).Text);
            }
        }
```

Now I have List and Employee object consists of the following properties
empID, empName,empAge,empSalary

Now for each empID from tempempList I need to populate the List

I am not sure how I can populate emps.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List<T>` object is just the strongly-typed version (generic) of `ArrayList`.  `ArrayList` is preserved for traditional purposes, and `List<T>` should be utilized when necessary.

You can call the `List<T>.Add()` method, just like you did for the `ArrayList.Add()` method.  So something like:

`emps.Add(yourValue);`

That should suffice.

Comment: Thanks. But where do I populate each employee object?